# is "keine blasse Ahnung haben" used somewhere

Tags: usage, regional

We have a new foreign employee and she said:

> "Ich habe keine blasse Ahnung."

We thought it was a mix of `blasser Schimmer`und `leiseste Ahnung` and was done because she is foreign. But she said it was something she looked up. So we looked it up in [PONS](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=blasse%20ahnung&l=deen&in=&lf=de/) and there it is.

Now we are wondering is this really used by native speakers and maybe in which region of Germany it might be common. Because we never heard of it here (Ruhr-area, Lower-Rhine-area)

Comment: @tofro or compare both, Ahnung vs. Schimmer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blasse+Ahnung%2C+blassen+Schimmer&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblasse%20Ahnung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblassen%20Schimmer%3B%2Cc0

Comment: English and Dutch have, btw. similar constructs (flauw idee, faint idea)

Comment: @tofro: die Ausdrücke gibt es, aber "faint" und "flauw" bedeuten beide eher "schwach", "flau" und nicht "blass". "Blass" wäre "pale" oder "bleek".

Comment: I live in the Ruhrgebiet and I have heard both "keinen blassen Schimmer" and "keine blasse Ahnung" here and on TV. I don't think it is regional.

Comment: "Inte den blekaste aning" ist auf Schwedisch ein sehr sehr gewöhnlicher Ausdruck. Hat genau die gleiche Bedeutung, nur steht hier das Adjektiv in Superlativ.

Comment: Not  very representative, but I use that expression quite a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Duden Volume 2 – *Das Stilwörterbuch* (2010) includes „er hat keine blasse Ahnung“ among other similar expressions:

> er hat kaum eine, [absolut] keine, keine blasse, nicht die geringste/leiseste/mindeste/entfernteste Ahnung von Mathematik

This entry has no special style or usage labels. Therefore, it may be considered normal language or neutral in style.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question whether it is used by native speakers (I'm from Munich): I never heard of "blasse Ahnung", but the other ones are quite common, I use them, too.